# Mocked redux store value returning empty string when it should have a value

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, jestjs, redux-mock-store

The following test should should return "Test Project" for

```
const projectName = container.querySelector('.Checklists-ProjectName');
```

but is returning an empty string. How can I confirm that the store is actually holding this value?

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode } from 'react-dom';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';

import Checklists from '../Checklists';

const mockStore = configureStore([]);

let container = null;
beforeEach(() => {
  // setup a DOM element as a render target
  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
  // cleanup on exiting
  unmountComponentAtNode(container);
  container.remove();
  container = null;
});    

describe('Checklists', () => {
  test('renders checklists from state and displays the project name', async () => {
    const project = { name: 'Test Project' };
    const store = mockStore({ project });

    await act(async () => {
      render(
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Checklists />
        </Provider>,
        container
      );
    });

    const projectName = container.querySelector('.Checklists-ProjectName');
    expect(projectName.textContent).toBe(project.name);
  });
});
```

In the `Checklists` component `useSelector` returns an empty string:

```
const { project } = useSelector((state) => state.project);
console.log('Checklists project :', project);
```

Comment: and `mockStore` how it's defined?

Comment: I added the rest of the file to the question. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

The entire state tree is `{ project: { name: 'Test Project' } }`, the selector function passed in `useSelector` hook selects the `project` state slice, you don't need to do **destructuring assignment**.

Change:

```js
const { project } = useSelector((state) => state.project);
```

To:

```js
const project = useSelector((state) => state.project);
```